# Is there way to add a child div to only part of its parent?

Tags: jquery

I'm making a checkers games using Jquery. So far I've created the checkers board, and making the game pieces is where I run into my problem.

I made the board using 3 for loops like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {   
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   
        $('<div class="blackBox"></div>')
            .appendTo('#board');            
        $('<div class="whiteBox"></div')
            .appendTo('#board');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   
        $('<div class="whiteBox"></div')
            .appendTo('#board');
        $('<div class="blackBox"></div>')
            .appendTo('#board');
    }
}
```

But when I try to add the game pieces to the blackBox class it adds a game piece to every black box on the board. Is there a way to just make three rows of game pieces using my existing code or should make the board differently?

You can see my full code at:
http://jsfiddle.net/1jcjwx6x/4/

Comment: Please show the code that adds the game pieces, since that's the code you're having trouble with. It sounds like you're just using the class selector, you need to be more specific, such as using `.eq(n)` to select a particular element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`:lt(12)`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to append the pieces to the first 12 elements.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bm61q9cz/)

```
$('<div id="pieces"></div>').appendTo('.blackBox:lt(12)').draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to just use another for loop, you could look at the [:nth-of-type()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) css selector. Possibly you could pass it a formula like n < NumberOfPieces.